# How do I use line continuation with a command cast to [void]?

Tags: powershell, syntax

```
[void](New-VM -Name $serveur -Template $template -vmhost $vmhost -datastore $datastore.name -description $description -errorvariable erreur -erroraction silentlycontinue)
```

Hi, I'm trying to split this line using `. It works without the `[void]`. It does not work with the `[void]`.

What am I missing?

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: Do you get an error? Or more likely do you get no output at all?

Comment: Would be nice to see what you tried that does not work. We can only guess right now.

Answer (score 3):

If this is just about having cleaner code consider using [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6) instead of backticks / line continuation.

```
$newVMArguments = @{
    Name          = $serveur 
    Template      = $template 
    vmhost        = $vmhost 
    datastore     = $datastore.name 
    description   = $description 
    errorvariable = "erreur" 
    erroraction   = [Management.Automation.ActionPreference]::SilentlyContinue
}
[void](New-VM @newVMArguments)
```

`Out-Null` would work just as well in this case. Splatting makes for easier code to manage then having to deal with backticks and such.

Answer (score 2):

How about using `Out-Null` instead:

```
New-VM -Name $serveur `
       -Template $template `
       -vmhost $vmhost `
       -datastore $datastore.name `
       -description $description `
       -errorvariable erreur `
       -erroraction silentlycontinue | Out-Null
```

Answer (score 1):

[Matt's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50065785/45375) shows splatting as the superior alternative to line continuations with `` ` ``, [boxdog's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50065442/45375) shows piping to `Out-Null` as an alternative to casting to `[void]`.

Casting to `[void]` to suppress a command's output requires enclosing it in `(...)`

Assigning to `$null`, yet another alternative, avoid this awkwardness:

```
$null = NewVM -Name $serveur `
              -Template $template `
              ...
```

However, just to show that a `[void]`-based solution is still possible:

```
[void] (Get-Date `
                -Uformat %s
)
```